# How to Compare Second Letter?

Tags: regex, ios, regexkitlite

I Use RegexKitLite FrameWorks.

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:@"Welcome"];
NSString *newStr [NSString string];

//RegexKitLite.h reference.
newStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:<How To Expression?> withString:@"?"];
```

I want "Welcome" convert to  => "W??????"; More generally, for `Apple` , `Banana Cake`, `Love`, `Peach`, `Watermelon`... I want to covert

```
Apple => A???? 
Banana => B????? 
Cake => C??? 
Love => L???
```

I Make a These Pattern (HeadLetter only Show)... All Word is Stored In NSMutableArray So I access

```
[arr objectAtIndex:i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:<Expression> withString:@"?"];
```

How to compare Second letter With RegularExpression?

Comment: I Want Regex Pattern(Second Letter Compare) Not Want Answer [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Welcome" withString:@"W??????"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a regex for this. Simply do

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:@"Welcome"];
NSString *newStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Welcome" withString:@"W??????"];
```

For more options, also see the `NSString` method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`

---

For the more general case you describe, this can be achieved by similar `NSString` methods, e.g.

```
NSString *newStr = [[str substringToIndex:1] stringByPaddingToLength:str.length 
                                                          withString:@"?" 
                                                     startingAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Not Simply I want Pattern Regular Expression Second Letter Compare...^^;;
You Answer is Novice Answer... I Want Regular Expression (Second Letter Compare)

Comment: @bitmapdata: I do not understand what you are asking. Can you please give a better example? My answer does what you ask in the question, so please explain better what you want.

Comment: Okay, I Have a Many Word... For Example Apple ,Banana Cake, Love, Peach, Watermelon...

I Want Covert Apple => A???? Banana => B????? Cake => C??? Love => L???

I Make a These Pattern (HeadLetter only Show)...

All Word is Stored In NSMutableArray

So I access [arr objectAtIndex:i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:<Expression> withString:@"?"];

Do You UnderStand? You Know RegexkitLite?

Comment: @bitmapdata: Your question is much more clear now. I've edited the question to include your latest comment. Please see the edit to my question above. This does not use a regex, but does achieve the desired result.

Comment: You're code is Occure Compile Error.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:]: out of range padIndex'

Comment: @bitmapdata: The `startingAtIndex` value should have been `0` and not `1`. Try again with the correction.

Comment: @bitmapdata: Glad to hear it. If this worked, then you can click on the little check mark to "accept" this answer as the one that worked best. You may want to go through your prior questions and do the same. Accepting answers is a good practice on SO to encourage people to continue answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, I'm not sure why you're insisting on using reg-ex?

[NSString characterAtIndex:] will allow you to look at a particular character at any position within a string.